# Do antigen presenting cells present only antigens they have receptors for?

Tags: immunology, virology, vaccination, mrna

As APCs  take up whole virus or bacteria  their receptors may be restricted to antigens "they have receptors vor", i.e. those antigens that are on the outside of virus or bacteria. Put simply: do they uptake "inner" antigens their receptor doesn't contact with AND, then, present them?

It should make sense for antigen presenting cells - APCs - to present only antigen that can be used for recognition. In other words: why should APC present antigens to T-cells if these cannot use such kind of antigen  to recognize and attack cells because those antigens are part of inner structural proteins that do not show on the external surface?

That may be different with B cells/MHC2.

Admittingly, this question is awkwardly put, as it should be known to any advanced learner that the APC's, the antigen-presenting-cells of the immune system have very broad receptor specifity. So there should be no antigen at all "they do not have receptors for" - same s for B cells as a wohl class or set.

I have not found any  or textbook passage on  B-cells taking up, via B-cell-receptor, "inner" antigens that come as cell debris. But then, the B-cell receptor in fact is a receptor in terms of my question. Which interestingly makes it seem a possibility that macrophages and dendritic cells have receptors that do not recognize any inner structural protein that comes as cell debris.

Having gone through and read Kuby, Janeway, Roitt on immunology, my understanding  is that not each and  every antigen of a  virus will find its way to the MHC complex on the cell membrane of antigen presenting cells. If that is correct,  how could eukaryotic cells possibly differentiate between antigen of viruses they present and those they would not? Do they present not "all sorts" of antigen but only those "they have receptors for" (awkwardly said)?

Regarding  "normal" cells of the body  that become infected and are not part of the immune system, do, for instance, CoV-19 infected body cells  present only the spike protein on MHC1?  The spike is the antigen they "have receptor for".

So any antigen that cannot be considered antigen to a receptor and becomes presented would answer my question to the negative. If so, is there any selection within that set of "inner" antigens ("non-uptake antigen").

Answer (score 2):

**"On MHC II, do cells present only antigen they have receptors for?"**

Thank you for boiling your question down to its essence. The answer is no. Professional antigen-presenting cells (APCs) such as macrophages, dendritic cells, B cells, etc., which present peptides in the context of the major histocompatibility complex (MHC) Class II to CD4+ T<sub>helper</sub> cells, initially obtain the source proteins through non-specific phagocytosis. Receptor binding doesn't necessarily have anything to do with it, unless you're looking specifically at B cells and antigen's binding to the B cell receptor (BCR) before being endocytosed.

[image: MHC II presentation]

<sup>*From [immunology.org](https://www.immunology.org/public-information/bitesized-immunology/systems-and-processes/antigen-processing-and-presentation)*</sup>

Where you might be confused about receptors is that only some of the peptides generated by cathepsin-mediated proteolysis in the phagocytic endosome have high-enough structural affinity to bind the MHC II receptor by displacing the CLIP fragment and being exported to the cell surface.

Comment: Very valuable advice on Clip "selection", thanks!Part of my "confusion" may be derived from viewing MHC as a kind of receptor. Anyway, question above may lead to better awareness of receptors that exist inside the cell - they do exist -, and MHC looks like one - which is, as it occurs to me writing this - as an unspecific one, like the others!

Comment: ... considerung "CLIP" in the context of "crosspresentation". Still cryptic, it's just a new look at things. If MHC were "some" receptor - then answer would go like: yes, of course, why you ask. - -  "Clip" to me denotes position at handing over of antigen betw. 2 "receptors", new view. – 
 See, for instance,   to illustrate Ciminski, "...findings show that bat IAV HAs make use of the major histocompatibility complex class II proteins of different vertebrate species to gain entry into host cells, ...".

Comment: Sorry, one more and last: not so trivial to see MHC as a "receptor", as one got to know: 1. there are "inner cell" receptors, and 2nd consider your word "affinity" in "enough structural affinity". To paraphrase: there are, do exist, antigens which there is no affinity for. There are antigens there seems to be no receptor for. Jokingly: no demo to/for/of them... no chatting: no mad demo for those.